# How to modify AndroidSlidingUpPanel.java in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am experiencing an issue with AndroidSlidingUpPanel and RecyclerView. Scrolling through the recyclerview is very glitchy and only works if I move my finger slowly. I have found this tutorial online which addresses this issue:

http://blog.naman-dwivedi.in/slidinguppanel-recyclerview

One of the things that this tutorial instructs me to do is modify the existing class to add some variables and refactor some functions.

How do I go about doing this?  In Android Studio it won't allow me to make edits.  From my research it seems that I'd need to modify a Jar file but I'm not too sure.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

-T

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed the issue by changing the sliding panel attributes in the layout file.  This achieves the desired affect, bypassing the need to decompile and re import a module